# Differentiate 2 directories on PyCharm with the same name

Tags: directory, ide, pycharm, names

I'm using PyCharm for a Django/Python project. In my project, there are two directories, named helloworld and HelloWorld. At the left of PyCharm, in my project tree, I only can see one of those, anyone know how to see the 2 at the same time? Both contains different things.

Directories folder:

[image: Directories]

PyCharm folder:

[image: Pycharm]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, in Pycharm > Help > Edit Custom Properties, put :

```
idea.case.sensitive.fs=true
```

Now I can see the 2 directories with the same name in case sensitive.